# Replace same word in different lines with random word

Tags: notepad++

How to replace same word in different lines with random word in notepad++

```
test
test
test
test
```

Would replace with random string:

```
sdwd
sasd
wdsa
dsas
```

Comment: You can't do such job with Notepad++. You have to write a script in your favorite scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions, by themselves, do not generate random data. They can just match a certain pattern. They may also be used to substitute some patterns, but the replacement must be fixed or either based on the input data. So if you need some random replacement you need regular expressions and some programming language (tipically *scripts*)

Even so, If you don't mind **pre-generating some random words**, you could still achieve this task just with notepad++ via **macros**.

The idea is having a file with such structure:

```
The data
you want 
to substitute

<SOME DELIMITER>
a list of random words
there must exist enought quantity of words/strings
<SOME DELIMITER>
```

For example:

```
a test on the first test phrase
a second test on the second test phrase

some test some test
some test some test

some test some test
some test some test

some test some test
some test some test

@@@@@@@@
qpfdhong
vvbpkwhi
aqhvuxxi
vtgaxofv
vwclbdxf
ecspqfdp
qqfimcum
bfqznfsa
pjwzjvzz
ybgvxzcl
tvsxpczg
hczduhkk
ydryudel
gnayvwjs
lncmqude
spilblsk
@@@@@@@@
```

You can generate random words/strings on this page: https://www.random.org/strings/

So the idea is to use a macro to record these actions:

1. Replace first 'test' word with the first replacement word
2. Delete the first replacement word/string
3. Repeat until all words are replaced

Once you have recorded your macro, remember that **you can save it for later reuse**. So you don't have to record it again.

This is the procedure to record the macro:

1. Click on record macro button
2. Menu => Search => Go to (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>)  1 => Go
3. Search and Replace (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
4. Find What => `\btest\b(?=[\s\S]*\r?\n@@@@@@@@\r?\n(\w+))` (where 'test' is the word to replace and '@@@@@@@@' is the delimiter for the random words)
5. Replace by => `\1`
6. <kbd>Find Next</kbd>
7. <kbd>Replace</kbd>
8. Close Search and Replace dialog.
9. Search => Find (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)
10. Find what => `@@@@@@@@\r?\n\K`
11. <kbd>Find Next</kbd>
12. Close Find dialog.
13. Search => Bookmark => Toggle Bookmark
14. Search => Bookmark => Remove Bookmarked Lines
15. Stop macro recording
16. (Optional) Undo last replacement with 2 <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. This is just to test the whole substitution at once.
17. Play the macro with `Run a macro multiple times` button
18. Macro to run => "Current recorded macro" or if you already saved the macro, use the dropbox to search for it.
19. "Run until the end of file"
20. <kbd>Run</kbd>

Results:

```
a qpfdhong on the first vvbpkwhi phrase
a second aqhvuxxi on the second vtgaxofv phrase

some vwclbdxf some ecspqfdp
some qqfimcum some bfqznfsa

some pjwzjvzz some ybgvxzcl
some tvsxpczg some hczduhkk

some ydryudel some gnayvwjs
some lncmqude some spilblsk

@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@@@
```

Finally, here is a video of the process.

Remember that if you already recorded and saved your macro, you'll just need to run steps from 17 to 20.

[image: Random words rubstitution]