# Replace string with random number/string using regex

Tags: regex, random, replace, visual-studio-code, notepad++

I have a angular project, we are using a plugin to show loading indicator.

The function goes like this
`this.loading('Loading message')`

Here `Loading message` is written everywhere. I need to find that exact source.

What I want to do is,
replace the `Loading message` with `<random string/number>` so that I can get exact source.

I am using notepad++, visual studio code. Can I do that using regex or any other way?

P.S. I have tried every other way, it is not possible to find the root cause any other way!

*EDIT*
I have to replace this string from all the files of a folder

Comment: You only need a regex for variable strings. You might as well only search and replace here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace same word in different lines with random word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989779/replace-same-word-in-different-lines-with-random-word)

Comment: @Julio, that is very good solution. Not sure if it can work for multiple files.

Comment: How many files do you have?

Comment: Around 300 files in different folders!

Comment: If `Loading message` can be any string, perhaps it is possible to search in the parent folder in visual studio code using `this\.loading\('[^']+'\)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uBEUD1/1)

Comment: For a similar problem I used a scripting language (I used Perl) to find and modify all such strings to include file name and source file line number. Some languages have symbols such as `__LINE__` that provide the line number which allows for edits to the file. But it is probably not necessary to keep the exact line number s.

Comment: Well, If you load all the files at notepad++, It believe It still doable with macros. Since macros allow you to change tabs. You need to pre-generate a list of random words enough to use for all the files. You use that whole list on the first file, do the replacements and then copy the spare random words to the next file (and save and close the previous), then repeat to the end. Anyways... even if macros are powerful, I believe at this point a programming a script would be a better idea...